# Is there a way to use `py3Dmol` in `tkinter` in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want use `py3Dmol` in tkinter package is possible to do?

I wannted to use the PDB to view in tkinter package

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can add the view to a frame buy first creating the view then using the `add_to()` method to add it to a specific frame.

like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import py3Dmol


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

view = py3Dmol.view(width=600, height=600)
view.add_to(frame)
view.removeAllModels()
view.addModel(pdb_string, "pdb")
view.setStyle({'style_name': {'color': 'spectrum'}})
view.zoomTo()

root.mainloop()
```